# API Gateway: Insert requestId into request body using mapping template

Tags: aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

In AWS Api Gateway, I want to insert the generated `requestId` into the request body without having to manually type each entry in the original request body.

If this is the original request body:

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "age": "20",
  ...
}
```

Then I want to transform it into:

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "age": "20",
  ...,
  "requestId": $context.requsetId
}
```

I do realize that there is an option of inserting the id into the header, but I want to insert the `requestId` into the body instead. I also want to avoid typing each key-value in the original body because I want the requestId to be inserted regardless of the body structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [mapping templates](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#context-variable-reference) to add the requestId to the request body.

> I also want to avoid typing each key-value in the original body because I want the requestId to be inserted regardless of the body structure

You can use a template like this for that:

```
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
{
  #foreach($key in $inputRoot.keySet())
    "$key": "$inputRoot.get($key)"
    #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
  #end,
  "requestId":"$context.requestId"
}
```

Comment: This works well for simple json objects. It does not work well for nested objects within the json object as it places the object in a string. Any workaround this. I am trying to iterate through the nested objects but it outputs empty strings.

Comment: Could you ask a new question for that? I'll answer there

Comment: Hi @Lemour! Did you find a way to overcome the issue with nested JSON objects?