# API Gateway: Insert additional field into a nested request body using mapping template or flattening a request body

Tags: aws-api-gateway

In AWS Api Gateway, I want to insert the generated requestId into the request body without having to manually type each entry in the original request body.

If this is the original request body:

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "age": 20,
  "info": {
     "profile": "gamer",
     "status": 200,
     "score": 0.1,
     ...
  },
  ...
}
```

Then I want to transform it into:

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "age": 20,
  "info": {
     "profile": "gamer",
     "status": 200,
     "score": 0.1,
     ...
  },
  ...,
  "requestId": $context.requsetId
}
```

I do realize that there is an option of inserting the id into the header, but I want to insert the requestId into the body instead. I also want to avoid typing each key-value in the original body because I want the requestId to be inserted regardless of the body structure.

Another option would be to flatten the request body into the new transformed body but I had no luck trying to find how to flatten a json object using vtl.

This is a follow-up question from [API Gateway: Insert requestId into request body using mapping template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75894158/api-gateway-insert-requestid-into-request-body-using-mapping-template), the difference this time is that one of the fields in the json object is nested.